# What's the purpose of the [auto] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What's the purpose of the [auto](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto) tag?  It doesn't have a tag wiki or usage guidance, has 8 questions, and seems to be (to me) a site-tag: every question on the site could be tagged with it.  I'm of the opinion it's not needed, but if someone else thinks they can edit the usage guidance to make it clear, that would work for me too.

Comment: Well, there is a [tag:truck] and [tag:motorcycle] also?

Comment: Wow those aren't the greatest either.  But they're not quite as ambiguous as [auto] thankfully.

Comment: Yeah, just looked through the questions and all of them could do without the tag.  Can I get rid of it?  It currently means both [car] (as opposed to motorcycle or boat), and [automatic-transmission]

Comment: I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleared out [auto](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auto) as ambiguous. I made what I could into [automatic-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-transmission) and then deleted the tag from the rest. I then created a tag synonym to point it to [automatic-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-transmission) so it won't be used/created again. Yah, that wasn't a very good tag to be using, no doubt. Thanks Cullub for showing it to me.